# How to divide HStack into two equal parts and place image in the middle of each part?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to conditionally divide HStack into two equal parts and place a circle in the middle of each part, how can this be done?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Form{
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: As it is]

[image: That is how it should be]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use two transparent colors that fill equally available space and put images into overlay, which uses centred default layout, like

[image]

```
var body: some View {
    Form{
        HStack{
            Color.clear.overlay(Image(systemName: "circle.fill"))
            Color.clear.overlay(Image(systemName: "circle.fill"))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

One way to do it is to give the Images a `frame` with `maxWidth: .infinity`.  This will cause them to expand to fill the space:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Form{
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "circle.fill").frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                Image(systemName: "circle.fill").frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

[image: demo running in Preview]